# JComboBox getSelectedItem is return correct values but .equals not working

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

So I have a JComboBox, I am able to select each of the items within it just fine. In the System.out.print I get the correct values, though when I preform a .equals on the string "Create Map" it does not get caught by the if control statement. Am I missing something obvious here?

```
mapSelectionBox = new JComboBox();
    mapSelectionBox.setEditable(false);
    Map aMapValues;
    for(Entry<String, Map> obj : runInfo.getHashMap().entrySet()){
        aMapValues = obj.getValue();
        mapSelectionBox.addItem(obj.getKey());
    }
    Object addNewMap = new Object(){public String toString(){ return "Create Map"; } };

    mapSelectionBox.addItem(addNewMap);

mapSelectionBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(mapSelectionBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Create Map")){
                xCoordinatesTextField = new JTextField();
                xCoordinatesTextField.setEditable(true);
                windowContainer.add(xCoordinatesTextField, "6, 4, right, default");
                System.out.println("Test");
            }else{
                System.out.println(mapSelectionBox.getSelectedItem());
            }
        }
    });
```

So I am starting to think that is is evaluating the getSelectedItem as an Object and not as a string as I have it stored in the hash map. Is this the case?

EDIT: I figured it out. I just changed this in the above code. Thanks for the comment.

```
String selectedItem = mapSelectionBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if(selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("create map"))
```

Comment: What does the `JComboBox` contain? `String`s?  Can you provide the code that builds the combo box and it's model? Also, try using `mapSelectionBox.getSelectedItem().equalsIgnoreCase`

Comment: I updated the code to include the rest of the class I am building. They are from a hash map but then the Create Map is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, the items in you combo box are not `String`s.  Trying to compare an `Object` using `mapSelectionBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Create Map")` isn't going to work, as `equals` won't use the `toString` method of the `Object` but will do internal comparisons of the state of the object instead.

Try using something like...

```
mapSelectionBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Create Map")
```

...instead...

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to see if a String is equal to a non-String object, one created by an anonymous inner class, one that only has a `toString()` that returns your String of interest, so of course the if test will fail. Now if you override the `equals(Object o)` and `hashCode()` of that Object to match that of the String, then you'll have a different result.

But more importantly, your JComboBox's model should only contain objects of one type, not Strings mixed with some anonymous inner class that has a funky `toString()` result.